# Is there a way to escape spaces in file names in vsftpd's config file?

Tags: linux, ftp

I am generating user config files for vsftpd on Debian Linux.  The config files are simple in nature, but I am running into one issue.  Is there a way to escape a space in the file name(s) for the `deny_file` or `hide_file` configuration settings?

Example - can I escape the space in `/Test folder*`?

```
# Example config file excerpt
deny_file={/Folder1*,/Test folder*}
hide_file={Folder1,Test folder}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this sub regular expression,

```
deny_file={* *}
```

Note: it's only applied on the last child of the path

Working example: /not_applied/not_applied/applied.here

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the standard linux syntax?

```
deny_file={/Folder1*,/Test\ folder*}
hide_file={Folder1,Test\ folder}
```

Comment: I have...  It does not work.  The folder is shown like it is not even denied/hidden.

Comment: Why must the folders have spaces? Would a folder symlink work? Eg:
`deny_file={/Folder1*,/TestFolder*}`
and have `ln -s Test\ Folder TestFolder`

Comment: The folders have spaces in them, because they are coming from a Windows machine.

Answer (score 0):

Since `deny_file` and `hide_file` have some regex control, you may try to replace the space with `?` or `.`

You will have to test both options though:

```
deny_file={/Folder1*,/Test?folder*}
hide_file={/Folder1,Test?folder}
```

and the other option:

```
deny_file={/Folder1*,/Test.folder*}
hide_file={/Folder1,Test.folder}
```